# Converting String to datetime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time, timedelta

I want to convert a column from excel from Object type to DateTime.

| index | Planned Hours | Actual Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2:00 | 2:00 |
| 1 | 1:00 | 1:00 |
| 2 | 1:45 | 1:45 |
| ..... | ..... | ...... |
| 18676 | 35:00 | 35:00 |

Formate of the column

Planned Hours - object
, Actual Hours - object

I used `time['Actual Hours'] = pd.to_datetime(time['Actual Hours'],format='%H:%M')` and i got an error as

> time data '35:00' does not match format '%H:%M' (match)

When I change the format to `time['Actual Hours'] = pd.to_datetime(time['Actual Hours'],format='%HH:%MM')` I get this error

> time data '2:00' does not match format '%HH:%MM' (match)

How can I convert the string values into DateTime without the error?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `Timedelta`, not `datetime` (which is what you would use for some actual date, but you seem to be working with time durations, not dates):

```
df['Planned Hours'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Planned Hours'] + ':00')
```